# Just how unreliable is -retainCount, exactly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pool, nsautoreleasepool

I'm looking to create an object pool that doesn't require the consumer to manually let go of the object. Instead, every time a new object is asked for, it checks all of the objects in the pool to see if their retain count is 1 (only owned by the pool). If it is, then it returns it.

How many hacks would be needed to get this general plan working?

**Example :** I know that some NSStrings that can't be released always have a retain count of -1, and that tagged pointers can't be deallocated (nor would I want them in an object pool). Would classes that aren't part of the basic set (NSString, NSArray, NSDate, and a few others), e.g. UIView, have fewer optimizations around retaining and thus be more reliable in their retain counts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`retainCount` is reliable for the information it provides but also probably useless for the use you have described.

`retainCount` tells you how many retains exist for an object (mostly, as you noted there are several exceptions for objects which cannot be deallocated). However it tells you nothing about who the owners of those retains are. In particular you cannot use it to determine if any of those existing retains are part of autorelease pools.

- An object might report a `retainCount` of `1` but the only remaining retain keeping it allocated might be part of an autorelease pool which will release and therefore deallocate it when the pool drains at the end of the current run loop.
- An object might report a `retainCount` of `10` but your proposed object pool might have the only retain outside an autorelease pool so by the end of the current run loop it will be back to `1`.
- An object might report a `retainCount` of `10` but they could all be retains from autorelease pools and it will still be deallocated when the pool(s) drain.

Additionally from your question it's unclear why you think you need this behavior. You can usually return autoreleased objects to your consumer. The consumer should retain the object if they intend to reuse it however regardless of if they do so or not your pool could choose to retain and reuse the object (or not).

Comment: The perf gain would be to avoid the expense of UIView's init method, by not having to destroy and re-create views continually. For the problem you mentioned, I think it's OK, because that just means that we would think it was being retained for the rest of the run loop, but then things will be correct for that view?

Comment: `retainCount` sounds like the wrong tool for the behavior you are trying to provide. It sounds like you want to create an object pool and allow reuse without reallocation of objects in the pool when no consumer of the pool is already using that particular object? If that's the case I would have the pool return proxy or wrapper objects to which the pool maintains a zeroing weak reference. Your consumers will then be the only objects to retain these proxies so you'll be able to check if the proxy is nil to determine if the object it wrapped is unused.

Comment: That's a cool thought, but it still requires unwrapping for every usage

Comment: That depends somewhat on how generic your pool needs to be you haven't given that much detail. A consumers of a non-generic solution should be able to interact only with the wrapper type and never need to know about the pools internal longer lived version. https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsproxy might allow you to build a more generic solution.

Comment: Good call! I might do that, as long as it's performant to do that forwarding

Comment: @meisel Have you measured view's init method as actually having any kind of performance impact on your program?   Reality check;  if it is, you're doing it wrong. :)

Comment: UIView is just an example. That specific class isn't too bad